# Where are the predefined functions in Lua's files?

Tags: function, file, lua, predefined-variables

I'm looking to create my own scripting language, highly based off of lua (im planning on it being lua but easier to understand for me) so I need to know where the predetermined functions / variables file is, because I would like to edit that. If you have a solution, please comment and let me know!

Comment: To disable standard libraries do not call `luaL_openlibs` when creating Lua VM.

Comment: See https://www.lua.org/source/5.4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every table in the standard library is defined in its own C file. In the `src` directory of the Lua source package, look for the file whose name is similar to the library name. Global functions are defined in `lbaselib.c`.